# I need help declaring an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```java
public class matrix {

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    int[][] matrix = Array();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my reputation is too low to comment I'll post an answer. In `isGPM` function in your loops when you check if count/sum is not equal to 1, in your first iteration it is always going to be 0 and return false, unless there is a number that is different from 0 on the first position in array.

The way I'd dodge this is to do it like this:

```
int count = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++)
        if (matrix[row][col] != 0) {
            count++;
        }
}
if (count != 1)
    return false;
```

You just move out the variable declaration of count from for loop and after the loop is finished you do the check. You can do the same thing for your other loop in the function.

Comment: I think you missed a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You need a count for each row for all columns and vice versa.

As you count upto 1 a boolean suffices: having found a non-zero element.

Instead of for row/for col and for col/for row which is a non space consuming fine algorith you could have done:

```
public static boolean isGPM(int [][] matrix) {
    boolean[] rowNonZero = new boolean[matrix.length];
    boolean[] colNonZero = new boolean[matrix[0].length];

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
            if (matrix[row][col] != 0) {
                if (rowNonZero[row] || colNonZero[col]) {
                    return false;
                }
                rowNonZero[row] = true;
                colNonZero[col] = true;
            }
        }
     }
     return true;
}
```

Above an array for rowNonZero is not needed as you see.

Your version would be:

```
public static boolean isGPM(int [][] matrix) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        boolean nonZero = false;
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
            if (matrix[row][col] != 0) {
                if (nonZero) {
                    return false;
                }
                nonZero = true;
            }
        }
     }
     for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
        boolean nonZero = false;
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            if (matrix[row][col] != 0) {
                if (nonZero) {
                    return false;
                }
                nonZero = true;
            }
        }
     }
     return true;
}
```